# How do I run a Qt app from python code in Windows?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5, spyder

When I run my python script I want the Qt GUI to appear. I have setup this up before on a LINUX system. Now I want to do it on a Windows machine but also, I don't have the .ui file (I shouldn't need it). I have a custom runlog_ui.py file and the file that the qt designer makes, runlog_qt.py.
I used to use the following setup:

```
prog_test = "runlog"
 
qt_dir= "C:/Users/Clay/Documents/runlog/"

out, err = subprocess.Popen("pyuic5 -x " + qt_dir + prog_test + ".ui " + "-o" + prog_test + "_qt.py", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()

from runlog_qt import Ui_MainWindow
```

so first off I know I need to take out the `prog_test + ".ui "` but nothing really working, i don't know what im doing.

Comment: If you don't have the ui file, then you don't need to call pyuic at all.

Comment: out, err = subprocess.Popen("-x " + prog_test + "_qt.py", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()

Comment: Is that supposed to be an answer?